# Loanwords: adapt spelling or pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, loanwords

Maybe "yacht" isn't the best example, but it was the "automatic choice" for me due to
[this Monty Python sketch](https://montycasinos.com/montypython/scripts/luxyacht.php.html).

Well, in Germany it certainly it's pronounced and written "Yacht" (or Jacht), not j-short o-t. (Since the word came from Dutch "Jacht", English changed the pronunciation, whereas the spelling just changed j to y, not a big deal.)

Thus my pet theory: Since English pronunciation is...eh, how to formulate it not insulting :-), I expect that loan-words from German imported to English are largely kept intact in spelling, maybe adapting pronunciation, whereas loan-words from English imported to German will rather adapt spelling to keep pronunciation intact.

If this is true, then just in a "statistical" sense (moreover depending on the age of the loan-word and whether English has an innate pronunciation problem - here the "ch" sound).

But is my pet theory true at all? What do the linguistic experts say?

Comment: What is the question?  Words are borrowed from language X to language Y all the time, the native speakers adapt them to their own phonetic/phonemic system.  German is just the same as English, except more Germans are also learning English (and have exposure to the English pronunciation) than English speakers are learning German.  I don't know "leanword",  is that a German expression? Its not in the English dictionary. I'd call these "borrowed words" or "borrowings".  Once they are borrowed, they aren't foreign anymore!

Comment: Or "loanwords"  I bet that is what you mean. we have a tag for that

Comment: I don't speak German, but I know that the Scandinavians spell French loanwords according to their own spelling conventions, e.g. Norwegian _paraply = umbrella_ ('y' being pronounced like the German 'ü'.)

Comment: Americans seem far more likely than Brits to retain foreign pronunciations - they refer to ***fil-AY** steak* and "aitchless" *fines **'erbs*** where we have our ***filET*** with ***Herbs*** (maybe even in a Cockney Londoner ***KAFF*** - a pronunciation I've never heard from an American! :)

Comment: @JamesK: Silly me. Edited.

Comment: [Yacht](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=yacht) isn't a recent loan word, and seems to come from Norwegian or Dutch not standard German. What's the Monty Python stuff about? It's kind of a stereotype to assume all English speakers have memorised the entire Monty Python sketchbook. As to the rest of the question, try looking at more recent loanwords from German to English, e.g. Schadenfreude, strudel, or Nazi.